# Does the algorithm of Google Map in returning a path from 2 points is the shortest path?

Tags: algorithm, google-maps

I just thought that if the "Get Directions" of google map returns the shortest path between two points. Any answers, comments and suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: what's the shortest path? distance? time?

Comment: Distance. But shortest path base on time would also be a help though.:)

Comment: AFAIK, usually when talking about large scale graphs, you try to reduce the time consumption by invoking a bi-directional search, which fails for weighted graphs, but is a good heuristic usually.

Comment: Thanks amit. But let's just say we are talking about small scale graphs. Does google return the path from 2 points the shortest path base on distance?

Comment: @John: Google's graph ain't small, I don't understand the question. Are you asking "what they are doing" or "what can they do?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about the [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/), we try to return the *fastest* path, not the *shortest*.